# Android Kotlin - How to set Spinner selected item

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner populated with array of strings from XML:

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerUnits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/units"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/labelGeneric" />
```

When user selects something, I save it to SharedPreferences. 
How do I set the value back when the app is opened next time? I have only the value saved, not its position in spinner's list.´

If I just do spinner.Units.adapter to get the adapter, how does one safely cast SpinnerAdapter! to ArrayAdapter? Or is this wrong approach?

Comment: Can you not save the position instead?

Comment: Then I'm in reversed trouble, as I need to show the value in several places... I suppose I could use the resource array, hmm...

But I'd still like to know how to do this properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to post the adapter code as well but here I am giving a sample how I will do in adapter.

```
 val adapterGender = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layoutCode, context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.genderArray))

 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val data = listOfItems[holder!!.adapterPosition]
        holder.etName?.setText(data.name)
        holder.spGender?.adapter = adapterGender
        holder.spGender?.setSelection(adapterGender.getPosition(data.gender))
    }

{
        val etName: AppCompatEditText? = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.etName)
        val spGender: AppCompatSpinner? = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.spGender)

        init {
            //listener for gender selection
            spGender?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }

                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    listOfItems[adapterPosition].gender = p0?.selectedItem.toString()
                    Log.d("TAG", p0?.selectedItem.toString())
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

so basically I am setting a `onItemSelectedListener` on *spinner* and listening for value changes and then setting it in model/pojo for persisting and assigning in `onBindViewHolder` for setting back values.

Comment: Aha, I was wrongly trying to get adapter from the spinner, but the correct way is to get it from the resource... which makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but for everyone who may be looking to a more compact and/or prettier solution; try querying the array you put in the adapter.

Assuming you've saved the values array separately, either in XML or in a class  field, and you know the selected value but not the position, you can get the position using the `indexOf` method and `first {...}` query.

So, taking your example, one could achieve this like so:

```kotlin
fun setSpinnerSelectionByValue(value: String) {
    val xmlArray: Array<String> = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.units) // get array from resources
    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerUnits) // get the spinner element

    spinner.setSelection(xmlArray.indexOf(
        xmlArray.first { elem -> elem == value } // find first element in array equal to value
    )) // get index of found element and use it as the position to set spinner to.
}
```

The `first` query will throw a `NoSuchElement` exception if no element in the array is equal to the `value` parameter, but it will be ignored and the position will default to 0.

If some magic is done on the array before inserting it into the spinner, the most common of which being inserting a null selector, there is most likely still a way of getting the correct position using the above technique.

When a null selector is inserted, for example, you could simply add `+ 1` just after the `indexOf` method and still get the correct position in the spinner.